# Why ENVI IDL writing gifs upside down?

Tags: envi, format, idl

I have a binary classification file shows urban areas. 
I need to convert this file to **8 bit unsigned integer GIF format.**

ENVI can't save images as GIF so I've used IDL and write a few lines to change the image format to GIF.

```
pro envi2gif
e = ENVI()
File = FILEPATH('1990_urban.tif',Root_Dir='C:\Users\urban_comparison\7tiffs')
image = READ_IMAGE (File)
filename = FILEPATH('1990_urban.gif',Root_Dir='C:\Users\urban_comparison\\final_')
WRITE_GIF, filename, bytscl(image)
end
```

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

How can I avoid this rotation ?

Comment: Probably something to do with top down pixel coordinates v.s bottom up map coordinates, try `REVERSE(image, 2)` http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/reverse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right Luke;

```
pro envi2gif
e = ENVI()
File = FILEPATH('1990_urban.tif', Root_Dir='C:\Users\7tiffs')
image = READ_IMAGE (File)
image = REVERSE(image, 2)
filename = FILEPATH('1990_urban.gif', Root_Dir='C:\Users\30M')
WRITE_GIF, filename, bytscl(image)
end
```

This code is working properly !